# set secure cookies chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I built a very simple chrome extension that takes selected text from a page, passes it as a query in the url of a dictionary site and displays the searh results as an iframe in the popup.

[popup.js]

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
  code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {
  console.log(selection);
  const query = encodeURIComponent(selection[0] || 'space');
  document.querySelector('iframe').src = `https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=${query}&ref=sa`;
});
```

How can I set SameSite cookies to "Secure" and appease the new cookie security requirements required by Chrome in the February 2020 rollout of M80?

The console for the popup shows at least 46 cookies are there:

[image]

But when I try to inspect the cookies from Application>Storage>Cookies, nothing is there

[image]

I've been stuck on this a few hours and appreciate your help.

Comment: This not something you can fix, unless you own pubmatic.com, if you do you just set the option on the path, i.e in php `setcookie('thecookie', '1', 0, '/; samesite=none');`, or if express etc has options built in https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie

Comment: I see, so it is something that the third-party website must resolve.
Will this cookie problem affect my app, which is just making get requests from a url? I'm not using the cookies for anything.

Comment: Extensions can use [chrome.cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) API to manage cookies in any way you want.